# Installing Puppeteer with Angular 13 throws dozens of "BREAKING CHANGE: Webpack < 5 errors"

Tags: angular, typescript, puppeteer

Specifically, installing it works without error, but the first time I try to use puppeteer, I get the dozens of errors.  I can't imagine that no one has come across this before, so I am reaching out to the greater wisdom of the internet for help.

Starts off fine with

```
npm i puppeteer
```

Then in a service I have:

```
import * as puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
```

with a function

```
async example() {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

    //const page = await browser.newPage();

    //await page.setViewport({ width: 1366, height: 768 });

    //await page.goto('https://tools4testing.com/');

    //await page.screenshot({

    //  path: 'example.png'

    //});



    //await browser.close();

  }
```

And as soon as I uncomment that first line, I get dozens of errors like:

```
./node_modules/minimatch/minimatch.js:6:9-24 - Warning: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'D:\Repos\TE\Lien Management System\client\node_modules\minimatch'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

./node_modules/puppeteer/node_modules/ws/lib/buffer-util.js:103:21-42 - Warning: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'bufferutil' in 'D:\Repos\TE\Lien Management System\client\node_modules\puppeteer\node_modules\ws\lib'

./node_modules/puppeteer/node_modules/ws/lib/validation.js:109:22-47 - Warning: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'utf-8-validate' in 'D:\Repos\TE\Lien Management System\client\node_modules\puppeteer\node_modules\ws\lib'

Warning: D:\Repos\TE\Lien Management System\client\node_modules\ng2-charts\__ivy_ngcc__\fesm2015\ng2-charts.js depends on 'chart.js'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: D:\Repos\TE\Lien Management System\client\src\app\_services\puppeteer.service.ts depends on 'puppeteer'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies
```

It seems likely that I need to add one or two lines of code someplace and all these will go away, but I cannot find the solution.

I'm still new to Angular, so the talk of "polyfill" is Greek. Googling about it hasn't given me much help concerning this situation (a la Puppeteer).  I have no problems with the other modules when Puppeteer is not installed.

Is there a simple solution to this?

Comment: Have found a fix for this issue?